# Create records in AWS Route 53 for ACM certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-route53, aws-acm

**/acm** - main.tf

```
resource "aws_acm_certificate" "test" {
  domain_name       = "www.example.com"
  validation_method = "DNS"

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

outputs.tf

```
output "Example_ACM_Cert_arn" {
  description = "ACM certificate for "Example""
  value       = aws_acm_certificate.Example.arn
}
```

**route 53/**
main.tf

```
resource "aws_route53_record" ""www.example.com"" {
  zone_id = var.example_zone_id
  name    = "www.example.com"
  type    = "CNAME"
  ttl     = "60"
  records = [var.Example_ACM_Cert_arn]
}
```

variables.tf

```
variable "Example_ACM_Cert_arn" {
    type = string
}

variable "example_zone_id" {
    type        = string
    description = "example zone id"
    default     = "00000000000000000000" 
}
```

I saw this tutorial in terraform but i dont understand how to do it if the ACM and the Route 53 is not on the same module...

```
resource "aws_acm_certificate" "example" {
  domain_name       = "example.com"
  validation_method = "DNS"
}

data "aws_route53_zone" "example" {
  name         = "example.com"
  private_zone = false
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "example" {
  for_each = {
    for dvo in aws_acm_certificate.example.domain_validation_options : dvo.domain_name => {
      name   = dvo.resource_record_name
      record = dvo.resource_record_value
      type   = dvo.resource_record_type
    }
  }

  allow_overwrite = true
  name            = each.value.name
  records         = [each.value.record]
  ttl             = 60
  type            = each.value.type
  zone_id         = data.aws_route53_zone.example.zone_id
}

resource "aws_acm_certificate_validation" "example" {
  certificate_arn         = aws_acm_certificate.example.arn
  validation_record_fqdns = [for record in aws_route53_record.example : record.fqdn]
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "example" {
  # ... other configuration ...

  certificate_arn = aws_acm_certificate_validation.example.certificate_arn
}
```

Hello everyone! I'm new in Terraform and I'm trying to Create records in AWS Route 53 for ACM certificate  via Terraofrm but i can't figure it out.

Comment: And how are you trying to use the code you have? Are you using modules? If so, please add that to the question as well.

Comment: @MarkoE Hi marko, yes i'm using  modules /ACM (main.tf. variables.tf, outputs.tf) /Route53 ( (main.tf. variables.tf, outputs.tf)

Comment: Hi, also when you say you can't figure it out... what part? Are you running `terraform apply` locally from your root module and getting an error? If so what's the error msg? If ACM and route53 are not in the same module, that's where data sources come into play. `data "aws_route53_zone" "example"` is referring to a resource (dns record) already created with the route53 module.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.